# Searchkick - dynamic ordering and sorting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, searchkick

I have implemented searchkick for elasticsearch, but would like to order and sort my results based on column names and direction stored in my variables.

Something like the following:

```
@suppliers = Supplier.search(
    query, 
    where: {
      :active => true
    }, 
    order: {
      "#{@column}": :"#{@direction}"
    },
    page: params[:page], 
    per_page:  @per_page, 
    misspellings: {distance: 2}, 
    fields: fields)
```

But the part:

```
order: {
      "#{@column}": :"#{@direction}"
    },
```

does not work and throws error. 
Any idea how it should be written?

Thank you, Miroslav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is the solution:

```
order: {
      "#{@sort}" => "#{@direction}"
    },
```